# Winphone MP4 on ubuntu

Tags: windows, lubuntu, phone, compatibility, mp4

If I connect my Winphone to my Lubuntu PC with a USB cable and drag its Mp4 videos across the will not open (Unrecognized format).

If I take the SD card out of the phone & pop it into my USB2.0 Multi Reader & drag the Mp4 across they play perfectly. Any idea why?

Kernel      : Linux 4.13.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 14:25:01 UTC 2018
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.26-0ubuntu2.1) 2.26
Distribution        : Ubuntu 17.10

Phone Nokia 520